# xpath, choose element after other

Tags: xml, xpath

I have problem to choose elements from an xml document that are exactly after other element.
In this sample I want choose element `<c/>` whose is exactly after `<a/>` element.

```
<root>
  <object>
   <a/>
   <b/>
   <c id="1" />
  </object/>
  <object>
    <a/>
    <c id="2"/>
  </object>
</root>
```

And I want get element `<c id="2"/>`
I tried //object/c[  position()-1= (../a[position()])  ] but dont't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `//object/c[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a]]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//a/following-sibling::*[1][self::c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `//c[local-name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = 'a']`. I had to apply a few corrections to your XML file - the `c` elements aren't closed, and the end tag of the `root` element is missing.